# Dynamically rendering form elements and saving them in an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am having 3 **materialUI** TextFields which I want to render **n** number of times (that **n** will be a integer input from user before rendering the form field, here I stored it in a variable named **groupMembersCount**). 
I am using functional component in ReactJS defining an **array with useState hooks** as:

```
const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = React.useState([
    { fullName: "", phoneNo: "", gender: "" },
  ]);
```

This will be my main array to hold all the 3 values(user input) at their respective indexes.
I tried returning those **3 materialUI TextField** dynamically by this method:

```
{Array.apply(null, { length: groupMembersCount }).map(
                (e, i) => (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <strong>Member #{i + 1}</strong>
                    <div className="getIndex" name={i + 1}>
                      <TextField
                        id={Math.random()}
                        name="Name"
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="none"
                        label="Name"
                        onChange={handleGroupName}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        id={Math.random()}
                        name="phoneNo"
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="none"
                        label="Mobile Number"
                        onChange={handleGroupPhoneNo}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        id={Math.random()}
                        name="gender"
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="none"
                        label="Gender"
                        onChange={handleGroupGender}
                        select
                      >
                        <option value="MALE">Male</option>
                        <option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
                        <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                      </TextField>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              )}
```

Now in the name handler **handleGroupName** I am doing this to get the div(to get index [from its name attribute] which stores index to push this value in main array **groupDetails**):

```
const handleGroupName = (event) => {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("getIndex");  // get div 
    for (var i = 0; i < groupMembersCount; i++) {
      console.log("index is: ", elem[i].getAttribute('name')); // get the index number 
    }
  };
```

After doing all this I am having issues in few things:
 1. One of the form fields (TextField) with gender in name attribute, I'm unable to use **select** to create a dropdown (writing what is shown here causes a blank screen) so I commented it out.
 2. In **handleGroupName** handler within the for loop it shows the error as: UserDetails.jsx:434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined.
 3. I'm new to react functional component, not much experience in it, can anyone suggest some better ways to get values from those form fields for every render and club those as an object and store at different index in the main array, the structure of main array **groupDetails** defines how it should look like at the end.

Comment: Can you please post your code in codesandbox so that we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: @SahilPaudel yes sure, I have posted the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-https-5wcl7?file=/src/MultipleForm.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this example where I take an input that define `number of member` in the group. Then it shows `number of input groups` (name, phone and gender). After filling the info if you click on the `Show` button, you will see the results.

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function DynamicGroupMember() {
    const [groupMembersCount, setGroupMembersCount] = useState(0);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = useState([
        {fullName: "", phoneNo: "", gender: ""},
    ]);

    function handleChange(event, index) {
        console.log(event.target.value, index);
        let newArr = [...groupDetails]; // copying the old datas array
        let item = newArr[index];
        item = {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
        newArr[index] = item;

        setGroupDetails(newArr);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Number of Group: <TextField name="groupMembersCount" onChange={(event) => {
            setGroupMembersCount(event.target.value)
        }}/>
            {Array.apply(null, {length: groupMembersCount}).map(
                (e, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <strong>Member #{i + 1}</strong>
                        <div className="getIndex" name={i + 1}>
                            <TextField
                                id={`name${i + 1}`}
                                name="fullName"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Name"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id={`phoneNo${i + 1}`}
                                name="phoneNo"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Mobile Number"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            />
                            <Select
                                id={`gender${i + 1}`}
                                name="gender"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Gender"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            >
                                <option value="MALE">Male</option>
                                <option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
                                <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                            </Select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
            <Button onClick={() => {
                setShow(true)
            }}>Show</Button>
            {
                show ?
                    groupDetails.map(member =>
                        <Card>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                {member.fullName}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {member.phoneNo}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary">
                                {member.gender}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>) : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really worked. One last question. I am having a useState object that holds this groupDetails array: `const [state, setState] = React.useState({ fullName: "", phoneNo: " ", email: "", idProof: "",bookingId: "", bookingDate: "", detailsOfPeople: groupDetails, }); `  and within useEffect hook I am doing this `useEffect(() => {
    setGroupDetails(groupDetails);
    setState(state);
  }, [state, groupDetails]);`    now the problem Is the values we just took into that **groupDetails** array are not reflecting withing the state when I do **console.log(state);**

Comment: tough to understand by reading comment. can you please post another question with sample code and give me the link?

Comment: Also, please make it answer by clicking on the tick sign as it worked for you

Comment: ok thank you for letting me know to tick sign, as  I didn't know that. how should I share the link with you?

Comment: you can create a new question with proper example as you did it for this question. then copy the url of that new question and pasted it here as an comment

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062488/synchronizing-nested-array-within-an-object-in-usestate-hook

Comment: hi, as you already got answer, so I am not giving answer for that. thank you

Comment: You are welcome bro. let me know if you need any more help

Comment: surely brother, can we connect to some other way also? my handles: facebook; https://www.facebook.com/kushal.verma.313 , Gmail; vermakushal.28@gmail.com

Comment: sure. I will email you

Comment: I have one more query, in the dynamically rendered form fields, I want to trigger two props "error" and "helperText" in the phoneNo field specific to the index, but when I trigger the props are triggered for every phoneNo field rather than the one I am taking input in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214930/discussion-between-kushal-verma-and-khabir).