# Synchronizing nested array within an object in useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have defined a useState object as follow:

```
const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = React.useState([
    { fullName: "", phoneNo: "", gender: "" },
  ]);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    fullName: "",
    phoneNo: " ",
    email: "",
    gender: "",
    idProof: "",
    noOfPeople: "",
    bookingId: "",
    detailsOfPeople: groupDetails,
  });
```

I have done populating the nested array **groupDetails**, but when I do:

```
console.log("state object:",state);
```

The field "detailsOfPeople" that holds that array **groupDetails** shows nothing. But if I print "groupDetails" all values are shown.
Within useEffect function I'm doing this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setGroupDetails(groupDetails);
    setState(state);
  }, [state, groupDetails]);
```

Comment: [Did you read how `console.log` works and how to print objects?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: what's inside `state` when `setState(state);`? try `setState({ ...state, detailsOfPeople: groupDetails });`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev yes, I tried that, It goes into an infinite loop and nothing is shown on the browser, it's just in the console the warning count goes increasing infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React State hooks are working async so you shouldn't wait state change after the setState call. You can catch the end of state change via useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setGroupDetails(groupDetails);
    setState(prevState => ({...prevState, detailsOfPeople: groupDetails}) );
}, [groupDetails]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was helpful, I am new to react that's why didn't know that, next time I will keep those details in mind.